# Pandas understanding groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = {'a': ['xxx', 'xxx','xxx','yyy','yyy','yyy'], 'start': [10000, 10500, 11000, 12000, 13000, 14000], 'day':['2018-10-08',
'2018-09-26',
'2018-08-07',
'2018-10-04',
'2019-02-06',
'2019-02-10'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
df["day2"] = pd.to_datetime(df['day']).dt.date
print (df)
print (df.dtypes)



     a  start         day        day2
0  xxx  10000  2018-10-08  2018-10-08
1  xxx  10500  2018-09-26  2018-09-26
2  xxx  11000  2018-08-07  2018-08-07
3  yyy  12000  2018-10-04  2018-10-04
4  yyy  13000  2019-02-06  2019-02-06
5  yyy  14000  2019-02-10  2019-02-10
a        object
start     int64
day      object
day2     object
dtype: object
```

When I used `as_index=False`, I get output as below - it makes sense

```
df.groupby('a',as_index=False).agg({'start':'first','day2':'min'})
    a   start   day2
0   xxx 10000   2018-08-07
1   yyy 12000   2018-10-04
```

`question 1)` But why dont I get the column `a` when I run below?

```
df2=df.copy()
df4=df2.groupby('a',as_index=False)['day2'].apply(list)
print(df4)

0    [2018-10-08, 2018-09-26, 2018-08-07]
1    [2018-10-04, 2019-02-06, 2019-02-10]
dtype: object
===============================
```

I get that column if I don't use `as_index=False`.

```
print ("===============================")
print (df2.groupby('a')['day2'].apply(list))
a
xxx    [2018-10-08, 2018-09-26, 2018-08-07]
yyy    [2018-10-04, 2019-02-06, 2019-02-10]










question 2) why `transform` is not working?

df2.groupby('a')['day2'].transform(list)
0    2018-10-08
1    2018-09-26
2    2018-08-07
3    2018-10-04
4    2019-02-06
5    2019-02-10
Name: day2, dtype: object
```

`question 3)` is there any list of functions such as `max, min, first, last` that I could use along with groupby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st question with apply it will not show the column , but we can do `agg`

```
df2.groupby('a',as_index=False)['day2'].agg(list)
Out[15]: 
     a                                  day2
0  xxx  [2018-10-08, 2018-09-26, 2018-08-07]
1  yyy  [2018-10-04, 2019-02-06, 2019-02-10]
```

To fix the transform

```
df2.groupby('a')['day2'].transform(lambda x : [x.tolist()]*len(x))
Out[19]: 
0    [2018-10-08, 2018-09-26, 2018-08-07]
1    [2018-10-08, 2018-09-26, 2018-08-07]
2    [2018-10-08, 2018-09-26, 2018-08-07]
3    [2018-10-04, 2019-02-06, 2019-02-10]
4    [2018-10-04, 2019-02-06, 2019-02-10]
5    [2018-10-04, 2019-02-06, 2019-02-10]
Name: day2, dtype: object
```

However, for you 2nd question below is better

```
df2.a.map(df2.groupby('a')['day2'].agg(list))
```

For your 3rd question

```
df2.groupby(a)['day2'].agg(['max', 'min', 'first', 'last'])
```

Comment: thanks. coudl you answer the 3rd questions

Comment: @user2543622 updated

Comment: is there a list of of functions that i could use?

Comment: @user2543622 what you mean by list of function ? most of function can be use with groupby , when they are agg

Comment: i mean what are the difference functions that i can use ? could i get an entire list of available functions?

Comment: i mean what are the difference functions that i can use ? could i get an entire list of available functions?

Comment: @user2543622 you can find more info in pandas website ~ :-)

Comment: do you have a link for that topic? I couldnt find it :(